# Why does Google Translate screw up my html formatting?

Tags: google-translate

I've implemented Google Translate, and the drop down menu is on the left menu bar.  However, when I translate into another language, Google does not honor the 
 tags.  As an example, go to this URL:

http://test.oil-testimonials.com/essential-oils/8031/headaches-and-nausea-for-various-reasons

Then translate it into German.  You will see the Author, Views, etc. are no longer on their own line. The actual testimonial below that is now one big paragraph too.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!